# Can I set tag on HWND?

Tags: c++, windows

In android i can do it:

```
view.setTag(obj);
```

Is there any equivalent of this function in C++ in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_USERDATA`.
[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).